# How to fix "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" in Google Distance Matrix API using Ajax Api

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-api, cors, google-distancematrix-api

I have been trying to request data from google using the distance matrix but everytime I requested it throws up "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" using AJAX API.

Whenever I make use of PostMan it returns properly.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Obalende&destinations=Ikeja&mode=driving&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyBTo0RgT_iA87Hd76gX8zYixB3PZh3z454",
         dataType: "json",
         crossDomain: true,
         cache: false,
         success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
  }
})
```

This is the error returned:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Obalende&destinations=Ikeja&mode=driving&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyBTo0RgT_iA87Hd76gX8zYixB3PZh3z454&_=1555970031620. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, instead of running from your local file, host a simple http server and then hit your page from there.

Use the following command in terminal whilst in the working directory, for windows see this link [microsoft simple http server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/simple-http-server/9nt5t97khpqg)

```
http-server -p 4090 .
```

will allow you to enter your browser and enter the address http://localhost:4090  , the error should not happen when using this simple http server. If you are using php in your page and need to serve these pages use

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:4090
```

Alternatively, in Safari, enable the Developer menu, and inside it click the following option

[image]